# Is there a specification for the YUM metadata?

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum

I'm trying to find a trusted point of truth for the following `yum` metadata files:

- `primary.xml.gz`
- `filelists.xml.gz`
- `other.xml.gz`
- `repomd.gz`
- `groups.xml.gz`

I've been looking around the Internet, but I haven't found a definitive reference, or guide. Is there a concrete specification, or RFC for this, or is this open for interpretation and implementation?

I've come across these useful links:

- [Anatomy of YUM Repositories: A Look Under The Hood](http://blog.sweetxml.org/2008/03/anatomy-of-yum-repository-look-under.html)
- [YUM Repository And Package Management: Complete Tutorial](https://www.slashroot.in/yum-repository-and-package-management-complete-tutorial)
- [openSUSE: Standards RPM Metadata](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Standards_Rpm_Metadata)

But I haven't managed to find an actual specification for this. Does anybody know if there is one, or where to find more details?

Comment: Well, the [wiki](http://createrepo.baseurl.org/)  for the project that defines the format has the line: "FIXME The specification needs better and more current documentation and needs to be included here." So that doesn't bode well, haha..

Comment: I know! :) And I can see that the different Linux distributions have implemented their own interpretations of how it should work. We would like to implement a layout provider for YUM in our artifact repository manager (called Strongbox: https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/issues/845). We are trying to gather the requirements of how to properly implement YUM metadata support (here: https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/issues/993). This is why we're looking for a more definitive source of truth. We were hoping for an RFC of some sort... Any help would be welcome! :)

Comment: Time to dig into the source for `createrepo`...

Comment: Ask the YUM mailinggroup : http://yum.baseurl.org/